# Is it possible to edit sub element in iterable object recursively

Tags: python, python-3.x

I get some override elements providen with this kind of structure:

`(keys, value)`

I would like to use that to change value in nested object (dict and list). It could look like this:

`data[keys[0]][keys[1]][keys[2]] = value`

The hard point is, the number of keys can be variable. I have no clue how to manage this recursively.

Comment: We have no clue how to help you without a [mre]. The only thing we can offer is to use loops but it's hard to say how exactly with the information given...

Answer (score 2):

You can do the following (iteratively):

```
def setkeys(data, keys, value):
    *path, last = keys
    for key in path:
        data = data[key]
    data[last] = value
```

Or for a recursive solution:

```
def setkeys(data, keys, value):
    head, *tail = keys
    if tail:
        setkeys(data[head], tail, value)
    else:
        data[head] = value
```

Answer (score 2):

A functional approach using [`functools.reduce`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce) and [`operator.getitem`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.getitem)

```
from functools import reduce
from operator import getitem

data = {"a": {"b": {"c": 1}}}
keys = ["a", "b", "c"]

*suffix, key = keys
reduce(getitem, suffix, data)[key] = 2
print(data)
```

**Output**

```
{'a': {'b': {'c': 2}}}
```